# How to redirect to two different views in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm a newbie to the Laravel framework. What I want to do is to redirect the users to a wait page firstly, then, they'll be redirected to their homepage after the wait screen.

I wrote some code for this but unfortunately it does not work. I searched about it but couldn't find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
function order(Request $req){
    $data = [['user_id'=>Auth::id(),'order_note'=>$req->order_note, 'sugar'=>$req->order_sugar, 'amount'=> $req->amount, 'place_id'=>$req->order_place, 'beverage_id'=>$req->order_beverage]];
    Orders::insert($data);
    $this->redirectToWait(); // this is another function in the same controller.
    sleep(10);
    return redirect()->route('home');
}

function redirectToWait(){
    return redirect()->route('wait');
}
```

This code only returns to the home route, it skips the redirectToWait() function.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this only using PHP & Laravel.
You have to use JavaScript to load first page then second page.

**Controller:**

```
function order(Request $req){
    $data = [['user_id'=>Auth::id(),'order_note'=>$req->order_note, 'sugar'=>$req->order_sugar, 'amount'=> $req->amount, 'place_id'=>$req->order_place, 'beverage_id'=>$req->order_beverage]];
    Orders::insert($data);

    return view('wait-step-view-here');
}
```

**wait-step-view-here.blade.php**

```
...[SOME_HTML_HERE]
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.replace("{{ route('home') }}");
}, 10000);
</script>
...[SOME_HTML_HERE]
```

Comment: That's wrong. You _can_ do this with PHP/Laravel only.

Comment: I don't think you _need_ Javascript for this, looks like it can be done in PHP only

Comment: Then Show us how. Once response is returned PHP/Laravel doesn't have access to it and can't change `Location` Header

Comment: @shaedrich that is wrong. the server can only send one response at a time. you can't send two redirect responses to the client (or if you do only the first one counts)

Comment: @apokryfos is right, If you can write two redirect methods it doesn't mean that it will redirect two times. If you are using `sleep(10)` it means that it will return one response after 10 seconds

Comment: @brombeer care to explain how?

Comment: Stated in my comment already, redirect to the wait page, `sleep(10)` there, then redirect to home. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: @brombeer once you send a redirect response, the server is done processing the request

Comment: I tried the proposed solutions but I could not do it with PHP/Laravel only. However, @MalkhaziDartsmelidze 's solution worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: While `sleep()` might not work on the wait page, you could still place a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/home">` in the corresponding wait page. I still stand by my point that "_You can't do this only using PHP & Laravel. You have to use JavaScript_" is a wrong statement

Comment: Yes, That's another way to achieve this. I was thinking to write `meta` variant there too